# Opensource audio feature (fingerprint) generator

Tags: signal-processing, audio-fingerprinting

I've already had crawled some video info from Youtube. Now I want to use its audio source to give every video a "feature tag" to strengthen my video recommendation service.
Are there any opensource or free lib/tools to do such work?

I've tried some tools I found for using the keyword "feature extraction" like "bextract" in "Maryas", but the result is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

a finger print is a LIST of features that would allow you to uniquely identify a video and audio file.

Think of some real features about what you are working with that you could look at:

Range of 90% of Power in FFT
Beats Per Minute 
Instruments used (would required some MIR identification)
FFT Coeffs for every 30 seconds.

and the list goes on, there is never one size fits all approach.